# Valgrind output and rdtsc in disagreement...why could this be?

Tags: c++, optimization, valgrind

I am testing the latency of a couple functions from a library. In order to do so I use rdtsc() on entry and exit, i keep track of the resulting rdtsc values, a running min,max and count of times called (to get an average). When I look at a graph of the output I see an average of about 100 or so cycles but spikes of about 20000 cycles or something disturbing like that (which seems far worse than a simple branch mispredict, of the 3 or 4 branches in the function). I ran cachegrind and I got output like this:

```
==14038==
==14038== I   refs:      2,260,149,383
==14038== I1  misses:           10,408
==14038== LLi misses:            3,978
==14038== I1  miss rate:          0.00%
==14038== LLi miss rate:          0.00%
==14038==
==14038== D   refs:      1,100,962,403  (773,471,444 rd   + 327,490,959 wr)
==14038== D1  misses:           26,419  (     13,447 rd   +      12,972 wr)
==14038== LLd misses:           15,446  (      5,701 rd   +       9,745 wr)
==14038== D1  miss rate:           0.0% (        0.0%     +         0.0%  )
==14038== LLd miss rate:           0.0% (        0.0%     +         0.0%  )
==14038==
==14038== LL refs:              36,827  (     23,855 rd   +      12,972 wr)
==14038== LL misses:            19,424  (      9,679 rd   +       9,745 wr)
==14038== LL miss rate:            0.0% (        0.0%     +         0.0%  )
==14038==
==14038== Branches:        327,248,773  (297,539,058 cond +  29,709,715 ind)
==14038== Mispredicts:         980,262  (    978,639 cond +       1,623 ind)
==14038== Mispred rate:            0.2% (        0.3%     +         0.0%   )
```

where the misprediction and branch miss rates are so low it makes me wonder what is going on..how am i possibly seeing such high latency measurements on the order of 20K cycles so often? What are some more things I can look into to solve this mystery? What could it be?

In fact, something mind boggling is that one of the rdtsc measurements merely wraps something like this:

```
if(memberVarBool_)
{
    memberVarPtr->smallFuncWithThreeIntAssignsAndstdmax;
}
```

and this guy shows me a lot of "25" cycles things which makes sense but also a lot of oultier cases with about 2000 cycles!

UPDATE: I just switched to using gettimeofday to measuring latency in nanoseconds hoping to avoid issues specific to rdtsc and still see the same stuff...is there a way I can avoid preemption and outside-or-process effects in my meaurements?

Comment: Are you running on a real-time operating system?  There are lots of things that can interrupt your process.

Comment: Is your process ever preempted or does syscalls?

Comment: @Chad, I will try to run with ulimit -r99..but I'd like to rule out actual inefficiencies or problems with the code itself.

Comment: @PlasmaHH The code snippet I run has no syscalls...not sure about preemption of program but would this be the culprit?

Comment: @PalaceChan: Well, if your program is preempted and not scheduled for 100000 cycles, then your timings will show those 100000 cycles..

Comment: If you have the ability (if you're on linux) use `SCHED_FIFO`, with a realtime priority just above all other processes.  There are likely some `IRQ`s that you cannot move/still need to process, so take that into account as well.

Comment: @Chad, is that the best one can do in linux in terms of disabling interrupts/preemption and allowing a process to fully hog a cpu wihout any interruption?

Comment: You _can_ isolate cores from the OS (meaning the OS won't schedule a task to a core unless that is specifically affinitized to it), but even then there are some interrupts that will run occasionally.  The best we've done is schedule our process `SCHED_FIFO` with realtime priority just _below_ the IRQ process.  This guarantees the IRQs will run on schedule -- important for responsiveness, and also keeps too many IRQs from running in a batch (isolating this core for even longer).  RedHat MRG has good support for this type of tuning if you can swing the support costs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How do you ensure that the operating system doesn't schedule another task/process between two calls to rdtsc()?     How do you prevent a hardware interrupt from occuring between the two calls to rdtsc()?

Both cases will cause what appear to be a spike in the difference between the two readings.

Comment: Would running with ulimit -r 99 help protect against this? Or how can I either attribute to this or avoid this?

Answer (score 0):

If you keep the raw samples, you can graph them and ignore the outliers, or take a median rather than mean/average.  BTW, as well as preemption - another reason rdtsc may misreport intervals is that your thread's moves cores: each core has its own TSC register, and on many boxes they're not synchronised to the same value at any point in time.  Pinning the process to a specific core can help.  You'd probably need to be root to disable hardware interrupts, and I'm not sure how it's done in a user process context.

Separately, just because something nominally returns nanoseconds doesn't mean it does so in practice: many such functions jump by thousands of millions of nanoseconds with some slower-ticking driver; repeated calls to the function will return the same value until it jumps again.

Comment: Interesting, what is this about the same value until it jumps again? I observed quite a bit of repeated values when doing nanoseconds! And very specific amounts like 1000. I am looking at maxes because I am worried they seem so frequent (according to the "timing data" which i am beginning to question...)...does ulimit -r 99 guarantee no preemption? Is there a way to measure "user time" at very low latency that i can research?

Comment: @PalaceChan: that's exactly the problem - if you call an OS timing function in a tight loop, you'll tend to get the exact same value many times, then it'll jump by a multiple of real update period (usually the multiplier is 1, but if there's been some thread preemption, hardware interrupt etc. it could be more).  Maximums are important if you really need to know costs of branch mispredictions, cache line stalls etc. - people often think they do when it's insignificant to their overall program throughput, but maybe you do ;-).

Comment: `ulimit -r` isn't going to help by itself... you need to set up your OS for real time support and also have the application request higher priority.  Re "user time" - do you mean that in the usual sense of "not time in system calls"?  Anyway, I'm not aware of any particularly good solution.

Comment: BTW - I just assumed you know about the need to use rtdscp or cpuid to maintain your instruction sequence; if not you should do a little googling.  It screws with your execution pipeline and slows your function down so you've got to be careful what and how much you read into TSC readings (even more so when you've nested timers), but at least you've got the timing around the code of interest....

Comment: Yea I've read about serialization of rdtsc..but even with rdtscp i dont see clarity. I would ideally like no preemption to my process of any form. I've been googling for this real time support (I'm on linux) trying to find the closest to full cpu hogging a process can get..

Comment: @PalaceChan: why's that?  Just for the profiling, or you want it to run like that in your production environment / end-user's machines?

Comment: well I don't think I need it for the profiling. I am almost certain by now some of the ridiculous numbers I see every now and then are preemption related...but because of that I feel like it could improve performance to be preemption free.

Comment: That is very rarely a good idea, but depends on many things, such as: What kind of software are you writing?  Is it deployed on dedicated boxes that exist for no purpose other than running your software?  How many cores/CPUs do you have?  Could those boxes have significant I/O activity at the same time you want to hog the CPU?  Are you ultimately concerned about throughput or latency or really need to maximise both?